# Google Tag Manager: How can I access the basket content stored in an array?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm working on a Clients website, trying to send some data to an external tool using GTM. Products in basket are in an array in dataLayer and my goal is to send separate 'event' for each of the products.

So if I have 3 products in an array(basket) I need to send 3 'events' each with products name and price for example. I cannot use data layer variables here because I don't know how many products an array will have, unless there is a way to put a variable in the place of the object position in the array.

What I have tried is to store the array in a var and then use a simplest for loop to do an action as many times as there are products. This somehow works but I'm really stuck on how to go from there, how to access name, price etc to send this data further.

My test code

```
    var harry = '{{dlv - Cart - Product}}';
  
  for(var i = 0; i < harry.length; i++) {
    console.log(harry[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Silly mistake that led to too much googling, when you put dataLayer variable in
' ', it returnes object Object, I just had to omit those signs at the first line and everything works like a charm(switched to forEach as well).

Answer: var harry = {{dlv - Cart - Product}}